# Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/ with Setup new firebase app in react-native-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have install react-native-firebase for setup crashlytics everything fine but when run app got issue like "Crashlytics reports Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/"

Can you please help me if any step or setting missing on setup firebase crashlytics

I have setup as new firebase app

[image]

Comment: Which guide did you use to setup your Firebase project? I'm curious what your environment looks like.

Comment: Fixed issue by restart my macbook